# How to get the users name and surname with google sign in? I have the email already

Tags: javascript, php, google-plus

SEE BOTTOM OF THIS POST FOR ANSWER THANK TO THIS GUY: [How to get the users name and surname with google sign in? I have the email already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22335294/how-to-get-the-users-name-and-surname-with-google-sign-in-i-have-the-email-alre#answer-22336908)

Ok, I have been staring at the google documentation for what seems like an eternity (5hours!)!

All i want is the basic email, forename and surname, so far all i have been able to get is the email.

The google documentation has really not got me very far, there seems to be so many variations.

This is the php code i have cobbled together from a mix of google docs, stackoverflow docs and other github repositories. The end result in $attributes containts a 'payload' array with the email and a few other

```
<?php
//load the google client
set_include_path( WEBROOT_PRIVATE . 'authenticate/google-api-php-client/src/' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
require_once 'Google/Client.php';

//set our unique params
$client_id = 'xxx';
$client_secret = 'xxx';
$app_name = 'xxx';

//start the google client
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName($app_name);
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri('postmessage');

// Exchange the OAuth 2.0 authorization code for user credentials.
$client->authenticate($_GET['code_from_client']);

$token = json_decode($client->getAccessToken());

$attributes = $client->verifyIdToken($token->id_token, CLIENT_ID)->getAttributes();
$gplus_id = $attributes["payload"]["sub"];

print_r($attributes);
die();
```

Resulting in

```
Array
(
    [envelope] => Array
        (
            [alg] => xxx
            [kid] => xxx
        )

    [payload] => Array
        (
            [iss] => accounts.google.com
            [sub] => xxx
            [at_hash] => xxx
            [azp] => xxx-xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
            [email_verified] => true
            [aud] => xxx-xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
            [email] => xxx@gmail.com
            [iat] => xxx
            [exp] => xxx
        )

)
```

Is there another call i can pass to the $client to get the user forename and surname?

I am pretty sure I am meant to plug it into: https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get  somehow but i cannot see a clear way

**ANSWER:**

```
<?php
//load the google client
set_include_path( WEBROOT_PRIVATE . 'authenticate/google-api-php-client/src/' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
require_once 'Google/Client.php';

require_once 'Google/Service/Plus.php';  /* THIS IS REQUIRED */

//set our unique params
$client_id = 'XXX-XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$client_secret = 'XXX';
$app_name = 'XXX';

//start the google client
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName($app_name);
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri('postmessage');

// Exchange the OAuth 2.0 authorization code for user credentials.
$client->authenticate($_GET['google_login_code']);

$token = json_decode($client->getAccessToken());

$attributes = $client->verifyIdToken($token->id_token, CLIENT_ID)->getAttributes();
$gplus_id = $attributes["payload"]["sub"];

// After $client is authenticated
$plus = new Google_Service_Plus($client);  /* THEN PLACE THE $client INTO THE PLUS SERVICE */
$me = $plus->people->get('me');
$firstname = $me['name']['givenName'];
$lastname = $me['name']['familyName'];

print_r2($me);
print_r2($attributes);
die();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the `people.get` method of the Google+ API is the one you want.

Here's a sample that should help you: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/examples/plus/index.php

In addition to loading the Client of the PHP Client Library like you are already doing, you also need to initialize the Plus Client to be able to call the `people.get` method.

```
...

require_once '../../src/contrib/Google_PlusService.php';

...

$client = new Google_Client();
...
$plus = new Google_PlusService($client);

...

// After $client is authenticated
$me = $plus->people->get('me');

$firstname = $me['name']['givenName'];
$lastname = $me['name']['familyName'];
```

Comment: I cannot see the contrib directory within the src. Is this an additional download?

Comment: There is a require_once 'Google/Service/Plus.php'; available to use however

Comment: Working through google documentation is like dragging my face along a mile of course sandpaper! Scaryman you were correct but with the new API the sytax is slightly different: have put in post

Comment: Ah, didn't realize there's a completely new version of the php client library out there, glad you got it to work :)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure if this will help you but, I use a class called LightOpenID and in it:

```
$openid = new LightOpenID($doc_root);

$openid->identity = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id';
$openid->required = array(
    'namePerson/first',
    'namePerson/last',
    'contact/email',
);
```

Then I can use:

```
$data = $openid->getAttributes();
$email = $data['contact/email'];
$first = $data['namePerson/first'];
```

That's the only help I can provide as this is the only library I use with Google OpenID

Comment: Thanks i will keep it in mind but i do want to use the google api preferably.

Comment: I believe this falls under the [deprecated auth methods](https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration).

Comment: Thanks abraham I'll have to check that out.